# How do I specify an array with multiple objects in a TypeScript interface?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux

I have some React-Redux-Typescript code, and I am getting results from an API and trying to create interfaces for the response objects. Here I have my Example data:

```
    const exampleState: ExampleState = {
  loading: false,
  products: {
    "id": 11001,
    "campus": "hrnyc",
    "name": "Camo Onesie",
    "slogan": "Blend in to your crowd",
    "description": "The So Fatigues will wake you up and fit you in. This high energy camo will have you blending in to even the wildest surroundings.",
    "category": "Jackets",
    "default_price": "140.00",
    "created_at": "2021-01-12T21:17:59.200Z",
    "updated_at": "2021-01-12T21:17:59.200Z",
    "features": [
        {
            "feature": "Fabric",
            "value": "Canvas"
        },
        {
            "feature": "Buttons",
            "value": "Brass"
        }
    ]
  }
};
```

and here is my interface for this object:

```
export interface Featured {
  "id": number
  "campus": string,
  "name": string,
  "slogan": string,
  "description": string,
  "category": string,
  "default_price": string,
  "created_at": string,
  "updated_at": string,
  "features": [
      {
          "feature": string,
          "value": string
      }
  ]
}
```

I am getting the following error within my reducer:

```
TypeScript error in /Users/theo/Desktop/hrnyc34-fec-falcullele/my-app/src/reducers/singleProductReducer.ts(20,5):
Type '[{ feature: string; value: string; }, { feature: string; value: string; }]' is not assignable to type '[{ feature: string; value: string; }]'.
  Types of property 'length' are incompatible.
    Type '2' is not assignable to type '1'.  TS2322

    18 |     "created_at": "2021-01-12T21:17:59.200Z",
    19 |     "updated_at": "2021-01-12T21:17:59.200Z",
  > 20 |     "features": [
       |     ^
    21 |         {
    22 |             "feature": "Fabric",
    23 |             "value": "Canvas"
```

As far as I can tell the issue is that there are multiple objects inside of the 'features' array. There can be up to a dozen objects in this features array potentially. How can I remedy this typescript error?

Comment: You've specified a *tuple* type, not an *array* type. See https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html

Comment: @jonrsharpe You're completely right. Learning typescript on the fly currently. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The type you've specified for `feature` is a [tuple](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#tuple) - a fixed length array whose elements have known types. The following is what you want:

```
type FeatureType = {
   "feature": string,
   "value": string
}

export interface Featured {
  "id": number
  "campus": string,
  "name": string,
  "slogan": string,
  "description": string,
  "category": string,
  "default_price": string,
  "created_at": string,
  "updated_at": string,
  "features": FeatureType[]
}
```

(Note: I've extracted 'feature' out into a type alias for readability, which you don't have to do)

Comment: If you're extracting the feature type I'd still have the array part in Featured, then you have easy access to the type for each value in that array.

Comment: That's a good idea, I'll edit the answer.

Answer (score 0):

*features* -- Key Value Pair in the Object has an Array type with an same Object Type which has key value pairs *feature,value* are repeated inside the Array multiple times (no fixed length) -- this refers to **tuple** -- a Typescript feature which helps us to easily declare the same Object to check for any type,lint,compilation errors

```
interface Feature {
            "feature": string,
             "value": string
}


interface Featured {
  "id": number
  "campus": string,
  "name": string,
  "slogan": string,
  "description": string,
  "category": string,
  "default_price": string,
  "created_at": string,
  "updated_at": string,
  "features": Feature[]
}
```

//export is used when the interface is declared in other file where we import the file to use the interface (mainly used in model files ,instead of interface we class)